# Print depth of call stack

Tags: objective-c, callstack

I'd like to log how deep I am in the call stack in the debugger. For example, if I call a method 7 stack-frames deep, I want to print "7".

Is there a way to do this in a language like Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
NSLog(@"%d stack frames", (int)[NSThread  callStackReturnAddresses].count);
```

However, this seems like a fishy thing to want to do.  Update your question with more details of what exactly you're trying to debug and we might be able to give you better help.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: Error:(29, 61) property 'callStackReturnAddresses' not found on object of type 'NSThread *'

Comment: [NSThread callStackReturnAddresses].count however does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Rob.